# where to store api keys in express node for Heroku

Tags: node.js, security, express, stripe-payments, api-key

I am finishing up a node express App where I have an API key for Sendgrid and Stripe but I am not sure how to store these in my app that will be deployed on Heroku (also a few other variable I would like to store similarly like db password and what not). I saw online many people were using `process.env` so after some looking I tried using `dotenv` npm and even with some problems with the structure of the app after trying to use the `dotenv` for my sendgrid key I got an error every time.

My question is can somebody supply some detailed instructions or a way to **securely** store API keys in my node express app that I will be deploying to Heroku?

P.S. I followed a tutorial to implement `Passport.js` for Oauth2 through facebook, google and linkedIn so users can easily log in to the application. The app secrets, id and callbacks are retrieved from a json file in a folder call config in my application. Is this information secure at least in its placement and retrieval in the application? Should I do something similar for my sendgrip and stripe api keys? (picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up your folder directory like this:

[image: config]

**config.js**

```
var config = {};
//development
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if(env === 'development'){
  config = require('./env/development');
}else if (env === 'test'){
    config = require('./env/test');
} else if(env === 'production'){
    config = require('./env/production');
}

module.exports = config;
```

**development.js**

```
var envFile = __dirname + '/env.json';
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var envVars = jsonfile.readFileSync(envFile);

module.exports = {
    value: envVars["VALUE"] 
};
```

**production.js**

```
module.exports = {
    value: process.env.VALUE 
};
```

**test.js**

```
module.exports = {
    value: 'Some value' 
};
```

The basic idea here is that each developer can configure their own keys in their own env.json file. For production, you can store these in a secure file somewhere and load them into the environment however you want prior to running your application. Using heroku, it makes it easy to configure these environment variables and stores them for you. Check it out [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

You can also ommit any details you may not need like development or test stuff.

**Edit: An example**

Try this from the command line first to get an idea of what is happening. In this example I am using linux. If you are using anything else just research how to set the environment variables in the command line you are using.

**app.js**

```
var config = require('./config/config');
//get value from config
var value = config.value;
```

**Set environment variables from bash command line**

```
$: VALUE="my value"
$: NODE_ENV="production"
$: export VALUE
$: export NODE_ENV
```

**Run the application**

```
$: node app.js
```

or if you are using npm scripts

```
$: npm start
```

When you run the application node will automatically load `process.env` with every environment varaible defined within the command line shell. Now, if you are using heroku you can follow the link I posted earlier in this answer and you don't have to set them. Just define them in heroku interface and it will load them for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response but I have questions, all about making sure I know whats happening at each step. 1) I'm assuming that the process.env.NODE_ENV will either be set by me as shell or Heroku system will make it 'production' when I deploy so it won't default to development, correct? 2) Does the `envFile` you added in the development snippet contain, as a JSON, all the KEY=VALUE pairs for my keys or do i put that in the `module.exports` portion you placed at the bottom and if that's the case, what goes in the `envFile`? Sorry its so much. I want to know whats happening as well...

Comment: Yes, correct. And yes, it will be standard JSON. Like this `{"VALUE" : "some other value"}` and nothing else. No `module.exports`. Of course, this is specific to my example. You can use anything you want (i.e. load from text file, yaml, csv whatever). The basic idea is the development enviroment should load values from a file you can drop in, production is defined in the environment variables, and test is usually hard coded in. So, just take what you need and it should work out for you.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah looking around everybody mentioned it but I didn't find much explicitly explaining the code. Maybe I just wasn't looking. Before I go and put this in my project Id like to ask one more question. After doing this and getting all my values in place in this way will it be secure? I'm not looking for fort knox here but just enough so that I have the basics covered and no one can easily take my keys

Comment: Oh and should I make any changes to the original P.S. i posted about my Oauth with `Passport.js` or is that good?

Comment: Well with the current setup your API keys will not be committed to source. Any other security concerns are dependent upon how secure your server (heroku) is. I don't have much experience with heroku so you will have to research it, but I'd say you should be safe. Lastly, I use passport.js and it is good. :)

Comment: Thanks Corey. You were a big help. Check and up votes all the way. I'll keep you posted on if it goes well

Comment: Glad to hear. Take care!

Comment: I get when you say `production is defined in the environment variables`  and thats why I tried the npm `dotenv` but that didn't work out for me. So how would I set my `process.env` variables for production? would it be as you specified in the snippet above in `production.js`? Example= `module.exports{ "my_database" : process.env.DB_NAME}`

Comment: Dotenv is used to load variables from a file to the environment. Sort of like how I explained in the development. If you are using heroku, the environment variables can be configured prior to running your program. In node, whenever the environment variables they are set they are automatically attached to process.env when the program starts up. So you don't really need to "set" them specifically. Also, the answer I gave above was given without the intention of using dotenv.

Comment: Essentially, once you set the environment variables in heroku. You won't need to use dotenv in production. It will work right away as long as you define the names of those API keys in production.js. Just make sure anywhere in your app you get the keys by loading config.js.

Comment: Ok so I will need to `require` and path to config but the order of setting these aren't clicking for me. if production.js would I do something like this? `module.exports{ "my_database" : process.env.DB_NAME}` etc...

Comment: Yeah. That is what you need except it should be valid JavaScript. So, it would be `module.exports = { my_database : process.env.DB_NAME }`.

Comment: I can't get it working Corey. is there any chance in your original you can go through every single step with an example or two? l

Comment: Ok, would you like me to include dotenv in my solution?

Comment: No, id rather do what you originally suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129070/discussion-between-corey-berigan-and-kellysontop23).